# Sending/Reciving Text messsage between client and server

Tags: android, text

Now i can send message from (android mobile) client to (system) local server, but i want to implement sending text message from (android mobile) client to (android mobile) server.["Issue is now can send text message to server but it's display when i run logcat that message display in logcat page"].

Please give me solution, All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

use xmpp client for sending messages between mobiles.

[look at here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/)